# How to check if the Firefox Driver is opened in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm working in WinForms C# with Selenium Firefox WebDrivers and I'm using a code like this to close the driver:

```
driver.Close();
```

But I'm often getting errors that the driver is already closed. How can I check if the driver is opened (or already closed) ?

Also if anyone here knows how could I hide it in c#? Like hide to FireFox Window.

Answer (score 1):

You can query webDriver for a current window handle. If it exists, then call quit.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(driver.CurrentWindowHandle))
{
     driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Didn't work said .... An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ***********.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I would expect NullReferenceException if driver is already null.

Comment: An unhandled ******.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

use a try catch block.

```
try
{

driver.Close(); 
//driver will be closed if it is opened

}

catch(Exception ex)
{
   //if driver is already closed, your code will not crash due to catch block.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverException is thrown if try to call driver.CurrentWindowHandle after driver closed.  Good idea to make exception as specific as possible, so catch WebDriverException.

```
try
{
    driver.Quit();
}
catch (WebDriverException e)
{
    // Happens when call Quit but driver already closed.  Can be ignored.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ı solved the same problem

```
if (driver != null)
{
    driver.Dispose();
}
```